# Duplicate entry on autoincrement column

Tags: mysql, linq, insert, primary-key, auto-increment

I be with a problem in insert values, the mysql error returned is

> #1062 "Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'", but the primary-key of table is a not null,unsigned,autoincrement, column.

Below have a image with **four items**.

[image]

at item **1** can see the atual primary Value, 0 zero.

On item **2** have the error when execute dba.SaveChanges();

On item **3** u can see the last item inserted on table.

On item **4** u can see the autoincrement value.

Take a look on the value space between last inserted item code and autoincrement value. When try to add a new item on table, return a error, the autoincrement is increased but the item do not be inserted.

somebody have any idea why it occurs?

Comment: These results are the least interesting part. Show the code that **gives rise to these results**.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
the problem are on a trigger, on insert i define a column value equals "", and the trigger after_insert_aluno need a valid value on this column or null value.